# Looping collision logic error

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have a loop that is supposed to detect and remove any objects in a list that intersect with an object being placed. The code is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < levelObjects.Count(); i++)
{
    if (levelObjects[i].BoundingBox.Intersects(mouseBlock.BoundingBox))
    {
        levelObjects.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

When encountering a situation where there are multiple collisions, it sometimes does not detect the collision. The intersection function is working fine. What is it about my loop that's causing this?

Comment: Can you trace out the properties of the bounding box's when the the miss occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're removing from the loop, you end up skipping elements.  A better option would be to loop backwards:

```
for (int i=levelObjects.Count() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
  // ...
```

This prevents the "skipped" object that you're missing now, since when you remove, and the indices shift downwards, you're only shifting objects whom you've already tested.

Answer (score 3):

When you remove an object at index `i`, the value at index `i + 1` slides down to index `i`. Your loop moves on to index `i + 1`, and never checks the new value at index `i`. You can avoid this by simply looping backwards.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove the levelObject at index i, you shift everything down by an index.  The next item is therefore now at index i.  An easy way to avoid this is to start at the end and work your way backwards, i.e.

```
for (int i = levelObjectsCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (levelObjects[i].BoundingBox.Intersects(mouseBlock.BoundingBox))
    {
        levelObjects.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove from the list which you are iterating! Either iterate over a copy or create a list of items to remove and remove them afterwards. Example (if performance is not an issue):

```
foreach (var obj in levelObjects.ToList())
{
    if (obj.BoundingBox.Intersects(mouseBlock.BoundingBox))
    {
        levelObjects.Remove(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove objects you're iterating with a `for` loop... You just have to handle the indices correctly.  Removal is only an issue when using `foreach`

Comment: Yes, that is true indeed. And the performance is better as well.